# Energy Capacity Bug / Where To Post Bugs?

Tags: screeps

Does anyone know where I should post bugs that I find?  I noticed one issue.

When a creep's CARRY body part is destroyed, the energy capacity of that creep is reduced as expected.  However, after healing the creep's CARRY body part, the carry capacity is not restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact [artch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964914/artch), one of the game developpers, or email them directly at contact@screeps.com.